# Case when in where clause to choose between two columns ,SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have two columns to choose between in where clause , both are date columns.
Date1 and Date2.

I have these conditions to satisfy.

```
When @temp1= 1 and @temp2= 0 then Date1 between (@startdate and @enddate)
When @temp1= 0 and @temp2= 1 then between (@startdate and @endDate)
when @temp1= 1 and @temp2 =1 then Date1 between (@startDate and @endDate) and Date2 between (@startdate and @endDate)
```

I have to write something like this

```
Case when @temp1 = 1 then Date1 between  (@startdate and @enddate) 
     when @temp2 = 1 then Date2 between  (@startdate and @enddate) 
     when @temp1 = 1 and @temp2 = 1 then (Date1 between  (@startdate and @enddate) and  Date2 between  (@startdate and @enddate)
```

Please help , thanks in advance

Comment: For both the question and accepted answer: when did `BETWEEN` start accepting parentheses around the range? It doesn't parse well in 2008R2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using `CASE` you can use `WHERE` clauses like this:

```
WHERE
    (@temp1 = 0 OR Date1 between (@startdate and @enddate)) AND
    (@temp2 = 0 OR Date2 between (@startdate and @enddate))
```

If `@temp1 = 0`, then the first part of first condition is satisfied and condition `Date1 between (@startdate and @enddate)` is not evaluated. If however `@temp1 = 1` then `between` will be evaluated. The same is true with `@temp2` and `Date2` condition

Comment: Thats simple and exactly what i was looking for , thank you dude